# Qt Webengine get the value of QVariant out of Lambda ?

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, qtwebengine

i want get value of text string from page loaded in QWebengineView but i dont know how to get the value from the new lambda method now they using in their api. I tried the code below but am not able to update the value of QString sub:

```
   QString sub;
   webviews.at(0)->page()->runJavaScript(js,[&sub](const QVariant &v){sub = v.toString();});
   qDebug()<<sub; //this contains nothing
```

Comment: At. the time you're running your `qDebug`, chances are you've still not updated `sub`. Try moving the `qDebug() << sub;` inside the lambda.

Comment: its getting updated inside lambda. i checked.

Comment: Then use the lambda to progress the program. Clearly, that's what you should do.

Comment: i want set the subs as text in a QLabel .

Comment: Then do, that's what you should do.